# Eating fruits for Breakfast and Lunch

Tags: fruits

I have gastritis problem when I eat fast food. This year am kind of low in budget and won't be able to afford fast food. I depend on fast food because I come to work every early like 6:00AM and leave office like 10:00PM.

By eating apple, pear or others everyday for breakfast and lunch is enough to keep me healthly and hunger free?

Comment: If you have gastritis it would be best to see a doctor. They can recommend both an adequate diet and therapy if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everyone is facing gastric problem these days. There is not any permanent solution for this type of stomach problem when you take medicine you get relief for a day or two but i recommend you to use [aloe vera juice](http://www.womentune.com/article/health-and-beauty-products-of-aloe-vera-79) daily empty stomach regularly for 3 months then you will see the difference. The regular use of aloe vera juice removes constipation and all other stomach problems permanently from root.